# ggh4x::facet_grid2() - Is there a way to have free & independent scales on the x axis, but for the columns to display the same scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, ggh4x

I'm using the `ggh4x` package for the `facet_grid2()` function, facetting on 2 variables (one for the rows, one for the cols).
The values in the y axis are different, and the range of the x axis is different, so I am using the `scales="free"` argument.
I want each of my facets to display a different x axis, so I use the argument `independent="x"`.
Is there a way to keep those x axis values independent for each row, but for the range displayed to be consistent between my two columns?

Below is a reproducible example to exemplify the issue:

```
iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(group1 = rep(c("w","x","y","z"), each=20, length.out=nrow(iris)),
         group2 = rep(c("A","B"), length.out=nrow(iris)))

ggplot(iris,
       aes(x=Sepal.Length,
           y=group1)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid2(Species~group2, 
              scales = "free",
              independent = "x")
```

My ideal result would have the x axis of the first row show a range of 4.4-5.6 for both columns, 5-7 for row 2 (both columns) and 5-8 for row 3 (both columns).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use `ggh4x::scales_x_facet` or `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` which both allow to individually set the scale for each or a group of panels:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(
  iris,
  aes(
    x = Sepal.Length,
    y = group1
  )
) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid2(Species ~ group2,
    scales = "free_x",
    independent = "x"
  ) +
  scale_x_facet(
    Species %in% "setosa", limits = c(4.4, 5.6)
  ) +
  scale_x_facet(
    Species %in% "versicolor", limits = c(5, 7)
  ) +
  scale_x_facet(
    Species %in% "virginica", limits = c(5, 8)
  )
```

[image]

**EDIT** Or instead of replicating the code one might use e.g. the `purrr::map` family of functions to create a `list` of scales as suggested by @eipi10 in his comment:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)
library(purrr)

scale_x <- iris |>
  split(~Species) |>
  map(~range(.x$Sepal.Length)) |> 
  imap(
    ~ scale_x_facet(
      Species == .y,
      limits = .x
    )
  )

p <- ggplot(
  iris,
  aes(
    x = Sepal.Length,
    y = group1
  )
) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid2(Species ~ group2,
              scales = "free_x",
              independent = "x"
  ) + 
  scale_x
```

[image]

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm trying to think of a way to reduce the amount of repetitive code. The best I've come up with so far is to get the ranges by facet: `rng = iris %>% split(.$Species) %>% 
  map(~range(.x$Sepal.Length))`. Then add them to the plot with one line: `+ imap(rng, ~scale_x_facet(Species %in% .y, limits=.x))`.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10. You are absolutely right. Was a bit in a hurry yesterday. And did not even realize that the desired limits simply reflect the range of ´Sepal.Length`. :D I added your suggestion as an edit. And I think there is no better approach than the one you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

One way to control the x-axis range by row would be to create separate facetted plots for each row and then combine them. Below is an example. We split the data by `Species` (the row variable). Then we use `map` to create a facetted plot for each level of `Species`. Within `map` we get the x-range of `Sepal.Width` for the given level of `Species` and use that to set the x-axis limits for each plot. Then we use `patchwork::wrap_plots()` to combine the plots.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(group1 = rep(c("w","x","y","z"), each=20, length.out=nrow(iris)),
         group2 = rep(c("A","B"), length.out=nrow(iris)))

# Create a list of plots, one for each level of Species
p = iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  group_split() %>% 
  map(~{

    # Get x-axis range for the current plot
    rng = range(.x[["Sepal.Length"]])

    ggplot(.x, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=group1)) +
      geom_point() +
      facet_grid(Species~group2) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits=rng) 
  })

p[1:2] = p[1:2] %>% map(~.x + labs(x=NULL))
p[c(1,3)] = p[c(1,3)] %>% map(~.x + labs(y=NULL))

wrap_plots(p, ncol=1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>